# Remove fraction in decimal place from java primitive double?

Tags: java

In Java I have:

```
double x = 0.800000000000002
```

I want to remove 00000000000002 form x and I want x value to be 0.8.

I don't want to to use decimal format, because it converts my double to String.

I want to keep x as double.

Comment: What about `0.802`? What is the general rule?

Comment: I want to keep it as double, because I need it later in my code for calculation

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear. Because it is. You have not provided with enough information to fully understand the question. Please read my comment above.

Comment: 0.800000000000002 is further from 0.8 than the closest double, 0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125. Did it arise from a calculation? If so, why do you want it to be 0.8, not 0.800000000000002?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution which avoids String formatting is this:

1. Multiply your double with a power of 10, effectively shifting the decimal period to the right at the position after which you want to truncate.
2. Round your `double` value using the desired rounding method, like `Math.ceil()`, `Math.floor()` or `Math.rint()`.
3. Divide your double by the same power of 10 that you multiplied it with in step 1.

For example, if you want to round your double to two decimal places:

```
double x = 0.800000000000002;
System.out.println(x); // 0.800000000000002
x = Math.rint(x * 100) / 100;
System.out.println(x); // 0.8
```

The concept can also be used to round to quarters and similar roundings, and it can be used in research about fault calculation.

You could put this in a library, like this:

```
public enum Round {;
    public static double round(final double x, final int decimalPrecision) {
        round(x, decimalPrecision, Math::rint);
    }
    public static double roundUp(final double x, final int decimalPrecision) {
        round(x, decimalPrecision, Math::ceil);
    }
    public static double roundDown(final double x, final int decimalPrecision) {
        round(x, decimalPrecision, Math::floor);
    }
    public static double round(final double x, final int decimalPrecision, final Function<Double, Double> round) {
        return round.apply(x * decimalPrecision) / decimalPrecision);
    }
}
```

Note: Keep in mind that doubles are based on powers of 2. Not all decimal values can be represented by doubles, they're only approximated.

Warning: I have not yet tested above code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you do, but sadly `0.8` **cannot** be represented exactly as a double.

If you want arbitrary precision then use a class like `BigDecimal`. (But in my humble opinion that class is a pig to use due to Java's lack of support for operator overloading).

The general rule for a `double` is that it needs to be a *dyadic rational* of suitable magnitude for it to be representable perfectly. For example, 0.5, 0.25, and all integers up to the 53rd power of 2.

Comment: Well `double x = 0.8d; System.out.println(x);` prints exactly 0.8.

Comment: That's because the formatter tries to bury the grizzly details, and is successful on this occasion.

Comment: 0.800000000000002 is further from 0.8 than the closest double, 0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125. It is not simply a matter of representation of 0.8.

Answer (score 1):

```
double number =0.76432;
  double value =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(number));
  System.out.println(value);
```

use according to your convinience .I guess this would be helpful .